# How do I sort a list by newest date?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, lambda

I have a BlogPost class with

```
private Date creationDate;
```

and I have a list of blogPosts in the controller

```
List<BlogPost> activePosts
```

I am trying to sort the list by newest date (preferably using lambda). Cant find anything on it.

I tried something like this but its sorting by oldest date

```
activePosts.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getCreationDate()));
```

Comment: It does work, are you sure that the line is being called? Also consider that the default sorting direction is ascending (0 index == oldest date), so if you want descending order, then you should reverse the comparator using `Comparator.reversed()` .

Comment: so what I have is listing them by oldest date. How do I implement the reversed on this method? I cant seem too get it too work.

Comment: Please clarify _but its not really doing anything_.

Comment: I realized that is sorting by oldest date. Sorry about that.

Comment: `Comparator` has a `reversed()` method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It doesnt let me use it while comparing for some reason.

Comment: `activePosts.sort(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getCreationDate())));` The `reversed()` mentioned by @Sotirios works too, but Java 8’s limited type inference causes problems, so you may write `activePosts.sort(Comparator.comparing(BlogPost::getCreationDate).reversed());` instead. `activePosts.sort(Comparator.comparing((BlogPost o) -> o.getCreationDate()) .reversed());` will work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one it will solve your problem:

```
activePosts.sort((o1, o2) ->o2.getCreationDate().compareTo(o1.getCreationDate()));
```

Comment: Nope, that didnt work either, think that sorts by oldest date too.

Comment: try exchanging o1 and o2 in the bracket